# Train from haarcascade frontface

Tags: opencv, cascade, training-data, haar-classifier

This must be a question that is often asked, but I cannot find an answer nor intructions on how to.

Is it possible to train a cascade model from the already train haarcascade frontface default? My goal is for the script to recognise specific people (i.e. me). I know there is a recongniser built in opencv, but it is quite slow on a raspberry pi compared to a cascade xml.

I am tryingto train a model from scratch, but with mixed results.

thanks

(fyi: I've also post this question on answers.opencv.org https://answers.opencv.org/question/231697/train-from-haarcascade-frontface/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the way stackoverflow is meant to be used. but as I said, I posted the question on the opencv website without knowing if it was often used. I had a very good answer, so if you wish to get the it, go to https://answers.opencv.org/question/231697/train-from-haarcascade-frontface/